# Losing stdout when running jetty in systemd using jetty.sh

Tags: jetty

When I run jetty as a systemd service launched using jetty.sh, I can't figure out where stdout is going, and nothing I do to redirect it to a file works.

My jetty.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Jetty Web Application Server
Documentation=
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=jetty
Group=jetty
Environment=JAVA=/etc/alternatives/jre_17/bin/java JETTY_BASE=/var/jetty-base/
WorkingDirectory=/var/jetty-base
ExecStart=/usr/local/jetty-home/bin/jetty.sh start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Nothing shows up in journalctl.  I've tried redirecting the ExecStart by adding > /tmp/jetty.log, but that file never gets created.  Any ideas?

--EDIT--

Here is my jetty config:

```
[ec2-user@wmm jetty-base]$ java -jar /usr/local/jetty-home/start.jar --list-config

Enabled Modules:
----------------
  0) bytebufferpool            transitive provider of bytebufferpool for server
                               ini template available with --add-module=bytebufferpool
  1) resources                 transitive provider of resources for logging-jetty
  2) logging/slf4j             transitive provider of logging/slf4j for logging-jetty
                               dynamic dependency of logging-jetty
  3) logging-jetty             transitive provider of logging for threadpool
                               transitive provider of logging for server
  4) threadpool                transitive provider of threadpool for server
                               ini template available with --add-module=threadpool
  5) server                    transitive provider of server for http
                               transitive provider of server for plus
                               transitive provider of server for security
                               transitive provider of server for servlet
                               transitive provider of server for jndi
                               transitive provider of server for gzip
                               ini template available with --add-module=server
  6) jndi                      transitive provider of jndi for plus
  7) security                  transitive provider of security for webapp
                               transitive provider of security for plus
  8) servlet                   transitive provider of servlet for webapp
                               transitive provider of servlet for jsp
  9) webapp                    transitive provider of webapp for plus
                               transitive provider of webapp for deploy
                               ini template available with --add-module=webapp
 10) plus                      transitive provider of plus for annotations
 11) annotations               ${jetty.base}/start.d/annotations.ini
 12) apache-jsp                transitive provider of apache-jsp for jsp
 13) deploy                    ${jetty.base}/start.d/deploy.ini
 14) gzip                      ${jetty.base}/start.d/gzip.ini
 15) http                      ${jetty.base}/start.d/http.ini
 16) jsp                       ${jetty.base}/start.d/jsp.ini

Java Environment:
-----------------
 java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.2.7-0.amzn2.x86_64
 java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
 java.vm.version = 11.0.2+7-LTS
 java.vm.name = OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
 java.vm.info = mixed mode, sharing
 java.runtime.name = OpenJDK Runtime Environment
 java.runtime.version = 11.0.2+7-LTS
 java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
 user.dir = /var/jetty-base
 user.language = en
 user.country = US

Jetty Environment:
------------------
 jetty.version = 10.0.17
 jetty.tag.version = jetty-10.0.17
 jetty.build = af15f12297adf5c5083e1f2f8f4c5974438bca25
 jetty.home = /usr/local/jetty-home-10.0.17
 jetty.base = /var/jetty-base

Config Search Order:
--------------------
 <command-line>
 ${jetty.base} -> /var/jetty-base
 ${jetty.home} -> /usr/local/jetty-home-10.0.17

System Properties:
------------------
 (no system properties specified)

Properties:
-----------
 java.version = 11.0.2
 java.version.major = 11
 java.version.micro = 2
 java.version.minor = 0
 java.version.platform = 11
 jetty.base = /var/jetty-base
 jetty.base.uri = file:///var/jetty-base
 jetty.home = /usr/local/jetty-home-10.0.17
 jetty.home.uri = file:///usr/local/jetty-home-10.0.17
 jetty.webapp.addServerClasses = org.eclipse.jetty.logging.,${jetty.home.uri}/lib/logging/,org.slf4j.
 runtime.feature.alpn = true
 slf4j.version = 2.0.5

Jetty Server Classpath:
-----------------------
Version Information on 26 entries in the classpath.
Note: order presented here is how they would appear on the classpath.
      changes to the --module=name command line options will be reflected here.
 0:                    (dir) | ${jetty.base}/resources
 1:                    2.0.5 | ${jetty.home}/lib/logging/slf4j-api-2.0.5.jar
 2:                  10.0.17 | ${jetty.home}/lib/logging/jetty-slf4j-impl-10.0.17.jar
 3:                    4.0.6 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-servlet-api-4.0.6.jar
 4:                  10.0.17 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-http-10.0.17.jar
 5:                  10.0.17 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-server-10.0.17.jar
 6:                  10.0.17 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-xml-10.0.17.jar
 7:                  10.0.17 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-util-10.0.17.jar
 8:                  10.0.17 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-io-10.0.17.jar
 9:                  10.0.17 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-jndi-10.0.17.jar
10:                  10.0.17 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-security-10.0.17.jar
11:                  10.0.17 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-servlet-10.0.17.jar
12:                  10.0.17 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-webapp-10.0.17.jar
13:                  10.0.17 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-plus-10.0.17.jar
14:                    1.3.3 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar
15:                  10.0.17 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-annotations-10.0.17.jar
16:                      9.6 | ${jetty.home}/lib/annotations/asm-9.6.jar
17:                      9.6 | ${jetty.home}/lib/annotations/asm-analysis-9.6.jar
18:                      9.6 | ${jetty.home}/lib/annotations/asm-commons-9.6.jar
19:                      9.6 | ${jetty.home}/lib/annotations/asm-tree-9.6.jar
20:                    1.3.5 | ${jetty.home}/lib/annotations/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar
21:    3.26.0.v20210609-0549 | ${jetty.home}/lib/apache-jsp/org.eclipse.jdt.ecj-3.26.0.jar
22:                  10.0.17 | ${jetty.home}/lib/apache-jsp/org.eclipse.jetty.apache-jsp-10.0.17.jar
23:                   9.0.52 | ${jetty.home}/lib/apache-jsp/org.mortbay.jasper.apache-el-9.0.52.jar
24:                   9.0.52 | ${jetty.home}/lib/apache-jsp/org.mortbay.jasper.apache-jsp-9.0.52.jar
25:                  10.0.17 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-deploy-10.0.17.jar

Jetty Active XMLs:
------------------
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-bytebufferpool.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-threadpool.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-webapp.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-deploy.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-gzip.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-http.xml
```

Comment: Jetty's own logging (if you haven't configured something else) writes to STDERR, not STDOUT.

Comment: I'm talking in particular about System.out.println(), which should be STDOUT.

Comment: You could easily have one of the many console capture libs or configurations active that will route System.out.println() to the logging framework within Jetty.  Edit your question and include the output of `cd /path/to/my-jetty-base ; java -jar /path/to/jetty-home/start.jar --list-config`